# "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error during the compilation

Tags: c#

I get the "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error when i compile the code at `string[] values = lineuser.Split(' ');` . Any idea?

```
namespace function
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

            float userscore,itemscore,result;
            string lineitem, lineuser;
            //float[][] a = new float[89395][100];
            //float[][] b = new float[1143600][100];
            float[][] a = Enumerable.Range(0, 89395).Select(i => new float[100]).ToArray();
            float[][] b = Enumerable.Range(0, 1143600).Select(j => new float[100]).ToArray();
            //float[,] c = new float[89395, 100];
            StreamReader fileitem = new StreamReader("c:\\ITEM_SVD_FULL.txt");
            StreamReader fileuser = new StreamReader("c:\\USER_SVD_FULL.txt");
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

             for (int x = 0; x <= 8939500; x++)
            {
                lineuser = fileuser.ReadLine();
                string[] values = lineuser.Split(' '); //<------the line's error
                int userid, factoriduser;
                foreach (string value in values)
                {
                    userid = Convert.ToInt32(values[0]);
                    factoriduser = Convert.ToInt32(values[1]);
                    userscore = Convert.ToSingle(values[2]);
                    a[userid][factoriduser] = userscore;
                }
            }

            for (int y = 0; y <= 114360000; y++)
            {
                lineitem = fileitem.ReadLine();
                string[] valuesi = lineitem.Split(' ');
                int itemid, factoriditem;
                foreach (string value in valuesi)
                {
                    itemid = Convert.ToInt32(valuesi[0]);
                    factoriditem = Convert.ToInt32(valuesi[1]);
                    itemscore = Convert.ToSingle(valuesi[2]);
                    b[itemid][factoriditem] = itemscore;
                }

            }

        }
        public float dotproduct(int userid,int itemid)
        {

            //get the score of 100 from user and item to dotproduct
            float[] u_f = a[userid];
            float[] i_f = b[itemid];

            for (int i = 0; i <u_f.GetLength(1); i++)
            {
                result += u_f[userid] * i_f[itemid];
            }
            return result;

        }

        private void btn_recomm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(txtbx_id.Text==null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("please insert user id");
            }
         if (txtbx_id.Text != null && txtbx_itemid==null)
          {
           int sc = Convert.ToInt32(txtbx_id.Text);
           if (sc>=0 &&sc<=89395)
            {
              for (int z=0;z<=1143600;z++)
                {
                  dotproduct(sc,z);
                }
               //Hashtable hashtable = new Hashtable();
               //put the result in hashtable
               //foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in hashtable)
                 //{
                   //Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", entry.Key, entry.Value);
                // }
            }
         }
            if (txtbx_id!=null &&txtbx_itemid!=null)
            {
                int uid = Convert.ToInt32(txtbx_id.Text);
                int iid = Convert.ToInt32(txtbx_itemid.Text);
                {
                    if (uid>=0 && uid<=89395 && iid>=0 && iid<=1143600)
                    {
                        dotproduct(uid,iid);
                        MessageBox.Show("The Score of user id "+uid+" is "+result);
                    }
                }
```

Comment: That’s a runtime error, not a compile time error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check you `lineuser` variable is `null`

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

         for (int x = 0; x <= 8939500; x++)
         {
            if(!string.IsNullorEmpty(lineuser) //<--- check the string is empty
            {   
                string[] values = lineuser.Split(' '); //<------the line's error
                int userid, factoriduser;
                foreach (string value in values)
                {
                  userid = Convert.ToInt32(values[0]);
                  factoriduser = Convert.ToInt32(values[1]);
                  userscore = Convert.ToSingle(values[2]);
                  a[userid][factoriduser] = userscore;
                }
            }
         }

         for (int y = 0; y <= 114360000; y++)
         {

            lineitem = fileitem.ReadLine();

            if(!string.IsNullorEmpty(lineitem) //<--- check the string is empty
            {

               string[] valuesi = lineitem.Split(' ');
               int itemid, factoriditem;
               foreach (string value in valuesi)
               {
                 itemid = Convert.ToInt32(valuesi[0]);
                 factoriditem = Convert.ToInt32(valuesi[1]);
                 itemscore = Convert.ToSingle(valuesi[2]);
                 b[itemid][factoriditem] = itemscore;
               }
            }
        }

    }
```

Now you can avoid the error.

Comment: Please note I see your question, the problem is arise when you try to split the string lineuser. You must check the string is empty before the Split function. That's all

Answer (score 1):

You haven't opened the `Stream fileuser` so it is still null.

Answer (score 0):

It is really a bad practice to open the file while you define the global variable in your class.
But as part from this, when you call `ReadLine` the result could be a null because there are no more lines to read and you don't check for this case.

Looking at the code shown above, there is no need to have a global variable for the filestream, so, the usual pattern when handling resources (OPEN/USE/CLOSE) should be followed for both files

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        string lineuser;

        // OPEN
        using(StreamReader fileuser = new StreamReader("c:\\USER_SVD_FULL.txt"))
        {
            // USE
            while((lineuser = fileuser.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                 string[] values = lineuser.Split(' ');
                 ....
            }
        } //CLOSE & DISPOSE
        ....

        string lineitem;
        using(StreamReader fileitem = new StreamReader("c:\\ITEM_SVD_FULL.txt"))
        {
            while((lineitem = fileitem.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] valuesi = lineitem.Split(' ');
                ....
            }
        }
```